# After sort, the dblclick function stop working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that set yellow in the background of the paragraph when occurs a double click.
It works fine until I call a function that sort those paragraphs.
After sort it, the dblclick doesn't works when the user click twice again.

The html page:

```
   <div class="row row-artigo">
     <div class="col-md-10 text-justify">
       <span class="artigo  highlight">                           
           I - Loren Ipsun Dolor;
       </span>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-2 text-right">
      <div class="botoes">
        <span class="qtd-voto">1</span>                           
      </div> 
     </div> 
   </div>
```

`highligh` is the class added after double click. The dbl click function:

```
$("span.artigo").on("dblclick",(function(e){    
    if ($(this).hasClass( "highlight" )){
        $(this).removeClass("highlight");
        is_marcado = 0;
    }else{
        $(this).addClass("highlight");
        is_marcado = 1;
    }
}));
```

The sort is based on the class `qtd-voto` as follow:

```
$("a#ordenacao").on("click",(function(e){    
    var $divs = $(".row-artigo");
     var ordenadoDiv = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {                
         return $(b).find('.qtd-voto').text() - $(a).find('.qtd-voto').text();
     });
     $("#container-artigos").html(ordenadoDiv);       
     $(".row-artigo").wrapAll($('<div class="article-post">'));    
}));
```

Any idea why is it happening?

Comment: because you use jQuery wrapAll. Dom element are changed and eventListener for your dblclick are no more effecient.

Comment: I got, the problem is that if I don't add the class article-post, I lost the design of the page. Any suggestion? Tku so much

Comment: I deleted the wrapAll, but stil not working.

Comment: may be use $("span.artigo").on("dblclick", "sub element'', function() { ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$("#container-artigos").html(ordenadoDiv)` replaces existing DOM content, effectively removes all associated event listeners. See https://api.jquery.com/html/#html-htmlString for explaination.

Register event listener on document will prevent that

```
$(document).on("dblclick", "span.artigo", function(e) {
  ....
});
```

Wanna see if it works?